# The name xxx does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, asp.net, controls

I am using the login control of asp.net and the Fileuploader.
When I leave the file uploader control outside the `<LoggedInTemplate>` it works but when I try to move the Fileuploader inside the `<LoggedInTemplate>` I get "The name xxx does not exist in the current context" and it referes to the C#.

```
<LoggedInTemplate>
    <b>Login ok ! </b><br />
        <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" />
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>" 
        InsertCommand="INSERT INTO aspnet_PicturesHome(pUrl) VALUES (@pUrl)"
        SelectCommand="SELECT pID, pUrl FROM aspnet_PicturesHome">
            <InsertParameters>
                <asp:ControlParameter Name="pUrl" Type="String" ControlID="FileUpload1" PropertyName="FileName"/>
            </InsertParameters>
        </asp:SqlDataSource>
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label">Foto upload: </asp:Label>
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" onclick="Button1_Click" Text="Upload" />
<br></br>
</LoggedInTemplate>
```

Comment: What does "xxx" actually relate to?

Comment: it relate to Fileupload1 and to sqlDataSource1
example:

The name 'FileUpload1 does not exist in the current context
The name 'SqlDataSource1 does not exist in the current context

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Main Edit:** You can access controls nested in a `LoginView` like this:

```
FileUpload fu = LoginView1.FindControl("FileUpload1") as FileUpload;
```

If they are in the `<LoggedInTemplate>`, you will want to make sure they are in fact logged in (and vice-versa for accessing controls in `<AnonymousTemplate>`: they should not be logged in), otherwise it won't find the control and `.FindControl()` will return `null`.

Reference:
http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t109239-accessing-a-control-within-loginview.html

**Edit per comment:** in your `Page_Load()`, if initial request (not postback) check if user is admin, and if not, disable the upload controls

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e){

if(!this.isPostBack)
{
  if(!Context.User.IsInRole("admin"))
  {
     //disable controls
  }
}
}
```

Comment: But i only want the admin to have the Upload function in the page so i dont know how i can solve this problem without the loggedintemplate. It's also strange that SqlDataSource1 and FileUpload one give errors and the Button_1 doesn't give a error and it is in the <LoggedInTemplate>

Answer (score 0):

You might have created another web page or webform. or maybe you just might have renamed the public class for the webform. in the Global.cs, the control is registered or exists in the first webform you accidently created. delete and created paste your code and it will be fine